# Why my Picker is not working on phone but it is working on web browser(React Native)?

Tags: react-native, picker

Hi everyone I'm trying to add a Picker on my app but on my phone(IOS or Android) is telling me an error but in web browser is working?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { Picker } from '@react-native-community/picker'

export default function UnitsPicker() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Picker>
                <Picker.Item label="C°" value="metric" />
                <Picker.Item label="F°" value="imperial" />
            </Picker>

        </View>
    )
}
```

I imported it on my main code.

Comment: What error is saying?

Comment: This error "Metro has encountered an error while trying to resolve module @react-native-community/picker..."

Comment: Have you checked if the file is in fact there? This normally happens when installing/updating libraries. Just close all your metro bundlers / consoles and start fresh.

Comment: No problem. May I answer to your question with my comment and you set it as correct answer?

Comment: Okay, answer my question and then I'll set it as correct.

Comment: Thank you I appriciate =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked if the file is in fact there? This normally happens when installing/updating libraries. Just close all your metro bundlers / consoles and start fresh.